# JQuery - класс active для родительских элементов

Tags: jquery, классы

Нужно чтобы класс **active** при выборе дочерних элементов присваивался родительским элементам. Помогите кто чем может!
Вот [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/Cova4/JLDZr/) для примера

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">21</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">22</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">3</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">31</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">32</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $("#navigation ul li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#navigation ul li a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
});
```

CSS

```
#navigation { clear:right; padding-top:28px; padding-bottom:47px; }
#navigation ul { list-style:none; }
#navigation ul li { float:left; display:inline; padding-left:29px;  }
#navigation ul li a { font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
#navigation ul li a.active,
#navigation ul li a:hover { color:#d91d2a; }
#navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    }
#navigation li ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
}
#navigation li ul li {
    float: none;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}
#navigation li ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
}
#navigation li:hover ul, #navigation li.jshover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слегка коряво, но по моему для вашей задачи нормально.

```
 $(this).parent().parents('li').children('a').addClass('active');
```